# Incompatible units: 'rem' and 'px' - Bootstrap 4.3.1

Tags: sass, compiler-errors, bootstrap-4

I am getting "Incompatible units: 'rem' and 'px'" when overriding the Bootstrap 4.3.1 variables in a custom override sass file.

I have tried positioning following paths on custom sass file on top of the file and last line of the file as instructed on Bootstrap 4 documentation.

```
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions"; 
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
```

Error in terminal

```
ERROR in ./src/scss/main.scss (./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/scss/main.scss)

Module build failed: 
$custom-select-feedback-icon-padding-right: calc((1em + #{2 * $custom-select-padding-y}) * 3 / 4 + #{$custom-select-padding-x + $custom-select-indicator-padding}) !default;
                                                                                                                                                                 ^
      Incompatible units: 'rem' and 'px'.
```

Comment: why `<br>` ? in css file ?

Comment: ignore the <br>

Comment: Did you figure out the solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `<br>` from the SCSS file first and this the problem of `calc()` function not the problem of `px or rem`.

## NOTE

`calc()` function is the inbuilt function of CSS, so whenever you call `calc()` in SCSS, you need to use `#{}` technique to use the variable

```
height: calc(100% - #{$body_padding})
```

Now I give you one example

```
$custom-select-padding-y = 50px;
    
$custom-select-feedback-icon-padding-right: calc((1em +  #{2 * 50px}) * 3 / 4 + #{$custom-select-padding-x + $custom-select-indicator-padding}) !default;
```

`2 * 50px = 100px` and so on after that, it cant calculate `1em + {random px}` so, its return undefined and compiler give error.

`calc()` calculates  `2 * 5px = 10px or 2 * 1rem = 32px`.

`calc()` cant calculate `2rem + 1em`, `1rem + 1px` etc.